# SQLAlchemy determine whether an Integer attribute is a Foreign Key or not using inspector

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm defining a sqlalchemy model like this:

```
class Dog(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'dog'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('owner.id'))
```

I want to use the inspector to figure out a type for each attribute, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the things I want, which include (a) a type for each attribute and (b) all of the other properties that I've passed into `Column`.

I tried the following:

```
for column in inspect(target_class).columns:
    print column.type
```

This returns:

```
INTEGER
INTEGER
```

but really I'd like something like

```
INTEGER
FOREIGN_KEY
```

or at least some way to recognize that I'm using the second Integer to identify another table.

What is the most correct way to do this? If possible, I'm also interested in grabbing all of the kwargs that I passed into `db.Column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the `foreign_keys` property on `Column`:

```
for column in inspect(Dog).columns:
    print column.foreign_keys
# set([])
# set([ForeignKey('owner.id')]
```

There are other properties set from kwargs, like `primary_key`:

```
for column in inspect(Dog).columns:
    print column.primary_key
# True
# False
```